# Should new tag "ui-automation" be created?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is already [uiautomation](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uiautomation) tag on SQA, but it's initially created in [.Net GUI testing of third party components](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9132/net-gui-testing-of-third-party-components) post as a tag about Microsoft UI Automation (UIA) accessibility framework.

But later it was used only as a tag for general questions about UI automation. Considering that new tag "ui-automation" should be created for general questions about UI automation.

**EDIT:** Another question is what should I do to overcome this problem after raising this question on meta?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree to divide between a Microsoft and a general tag. But only creating a "UI-automation" tag would be too less in my opinion. The "Microsoft tag" should be renamed too to make clear that it's not the general one.

Depending on how many questions are flagged right/wrong (in case of using the existing tag) we could make a new one for Microsoft and use the existing for general. But all existing questions must be revisted and maybe retaged, what can only be done by users who have editing rights as the questions per se are not to changed and so "normal" users failed because the script notices that nothing has changed.

Comment: You are right about more clear devision in name, so I'd propose "ui-automation" for general and "ms-uiautomation" for Microsoft UIA. As I see there is only one question tagged "uiautomation" is about Microsoft UIA.

Comment: I think your suggestion with "ms-uiautomation" is fine and as you already analysed the question retag this one with a new tag and rename the general I would say

Comment: I have edited the question: I haven't got enough privileges to create very similar tags (like ui-automation when there is already uiatomation) and rename existing tags and create tag synonyms

Comment: But succeeded in creation of 'ms-uiatomation' tag

Comment: Done. 'uiautomation' for general, 'ms-uiautomation' for MS UI automation framework. Thanks!